# How do I find Ask Different in the official Stack Exchange iOS app?

Tags: support, ios-app

I'd like to find and use Ask Different from [the official Stack Exchange iOS app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/stack-exchange) -- how do I do that?

Answer (score 10):

Press the list button (three parallel, horizontal bars) in the upper left hand corner of the app to reveal the feed and site list section of the application:

> [image]

With the list section revealed, press `EDIT` in the `SITES` section to edit your pinned sites:

> [image]

Press `+` in the `Pinned Sites` view to add a new site to the pinned list:

> [image]

Search for `Ask Different` from the list of Stack Exchange sites and tap it to add it to the pinned sites list:

> [image]

Rearranged the `Pinned Sites` list and then press `DONE`:

> [image]

Ask Different will now be available in the pinned sites list to view directly.

Repeat for any other sites you want to keep pinned in the iOS app.

Comment: +1, but FYI the sidebar selection has no effect on what gets shown in your feed.

Comment: @mhlester for the sake of pedantry: what determines the content of the Feed then?

Comment: It's a lot more complex than that, based on specific tags you happen to frequent, voting patterns and phases of the moon.

Comment: It's worth noting that search will check the URL, name, and description of the site.  So "Apple" will also get you there.